# What does a "meteoric rise" imply?

Tags: phrases, metaphors

Does the phrase "meteoric rise" connote that the rise is short-lived? Particularly bright? Generally lateral?

It just seems like a meteor is not the best metaphor for a triumphant and lasting ascendancy.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Not necessarily short-lived, however [this definition](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/meteoric) does include brevity

> Similar to a meteor in speed,
>   brilliance, or brevity: a meteoric
>   rise to fame.

And [here's a discussion](http://dbennison.wordpress.com/2010/10/05/meteoric-rise-of-the-falling-star/) on this with a counterpoint:

> its use certainly bothers Guy Keleny,
>   as he explains in The Independent’s
>   Errors and Omissions column:
>
> “Meteoric” has acquired a meaning
>   almost opposite to the one it started
>   out with. The writer… describing the
>   company’s rise as meteoric, meant to
>   convey that it has been swift and
>   spectacular. But meteors do not rise;
>   they fall. They blaze briefly in the
>   night sky and as quickly disappear. So
>   a meteoric career is one of
>   spectacular success followed by sudden
>   oblivion.
>
> I’m not so sure. Meteors travel very
>   fast indeed (albeit downwards) thus
>   perhaps justifying the use of 
>   ’meteoric’ in the phrase ‘meteoric
>   rise’. And the Oxford Dictionary of
>   English happily allows that one
>   definition of ‘meteoric’ is ‘very
>   rapid’.

Comment: +1 and meteors do not reach destination being burne on their way

Answer (score 8):

*Meteoric* in this case refers to speed, not direction. My Webster's gives it a figurative meaning of *(of the development of something, esp. a person's career) very rapid : her **meteoric rise** to the top of her profession.*

Nevertheless, since the direction a meteor takes is downward, the term may  occasion a little merriment, and I can imagine cases where it could be used ironically.

Answer (score 1):

From several sources:

> A *meteoroid* is a sand- to boulder-sized particle of debris in the Solar System. The visible path of a meteoroid that enters Earth's (or another body's) atmosphere is called a meteor, or colloquially a shooting star or falling star. If a meteoroid reaches the ground and survives impact, then it is called a meteorite.

Thus a meteor may transect the earth's atmosphere in any direction but always quickly and, by virtue of its speed and the finite size of the atmosphere, briefly. Thus a meteoric career is rapid and brief.